# The strings in my program doesn't save on the text file

Tags: ruby

I am working on Ch.11 of Chris Pine's 'Learn to Program'. The exercise asks to build a playlist  for which I need to randomly pick a few songs from every folder.
Here is what I wrote:

```
folder = Dir['/Users/M/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/**']
music_folders= []

folder.each do |f|
    f = f.split ('/')
    music_folders.push f[7]
end


def mix arr
    arr.each do |aa|
    songs = Dir["/Users/M/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/#{aa}/**/*.{MP3,mp3}"]
    shuffle(songs)
    end
end

def shuffle songs
    playlist=[]
    x = 0
    y = 0
    count = songs.length

    while y<4
        x = rand(count)
        if songs[x] !='used'
        playlist.push songs[x]
        songs[x] = 'used' 
        y= y+1 
    end
end
puts playlist
end

mix(music_folders)
```

So the command output gives me exactly what I want but I am not sure how to have them saved to a .txt file. Can anybody help me with this? THANK!!

Comment: What exactly do you want to write to file? The whole music_folders array, playlist or individual items?

Comment: I wonder what kind of output do you see. There is no single `p`, `puts` or any other method that prints to the screen. `while` returns `nil`, so `shuffle` returns `nil` as well. `arr.each` in your `mix` method returns original array, so `mix` returns the same (`arr`). In the end, your `mix(music_folder)` should return original array. That array may be contain `nil`s if your path is not long enough (I have short path). Well, I changed it to `f.last`. ps. You should check this methods: `File.file?`, `[].inject`, `File.open` or `File.write`. Last 2 methods are for writing.

Comment: Opps! I accidentally deleted one important line. I added it back. I used File.open + File. write! It printed the playlist on the command output and it does create a file but the file is empty...

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt - I would like to write the list of tracks from different folders written into a .txt file...Does that make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will read the files (a bit more complicated than necessary) and writes it to `/tmp/songs.txt`

```
ROOT = "#{ENV['HOME']}/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music"

folders = Dir["#{ROOT}/**"]
files   = folders.flat_map { |dir| Dir["#{dir}/**/*.{MP3,mp3,m4a}"] }
songs   = files.map { |file| File.basename(file) }

File.open('/tmp/songs.txt', 'w') { |f| f.write(songs.join("\n")) }
```